# NetSuite: Show alert on Item Receipt on Record Save not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, netsuite, suitescript

The purpose of my script is to display a message to the user when they save an item receipt after comparing two line items. If the item and location match, the alert pops up. I've never built a successful script and this is my first time using line items. Right now, the script will allow the user to click the save button but the record will not submit regardless of whether the item and location match. Also, the alert message does not pop up.

Is there something blatantly wrong in my code? Any and all recommendations, comments, and criticism are welcome.

```
function is1003GandLeach(){
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('itemreceipt', nlapiGetRecordId());
var count = record.getLineItemCount('item');
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++){
    var xItem = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'itemname', i);
    var xLocation = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'location', i);
    if (xItem == "1003-G" && xLocation == "Leach"){
        alert ("REMINDER – Glacial is diluted when received. Inventory adjustment to remove 1003-G and add 1003. Divide the total pounds received by 0.2 and calculate the new cost per pound. REMINDER - Inventory valuation should be net $0");
        break;
    }
}
nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
```

}

Comment: which script type are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Is your script a user event script?  If yes, then you won't be able to show an alert since a user event script is a server side script.  If you want your script to show an alert before saving the record, change your script to a client side script and use the Save Record event.

Answer (score 1):

xItem and xLocation doesn't have the values that you are checking.

> var xItem = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'itemname', i); //Reads the internalid of the item
>
> var xLocation = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'location', i); //Reads the internalid of the location

So the if condition in your code will fails always. So to make it work you have to do the code change the api nlapiGetLineItemValue to nlapiGetLineItemText

```
//Reads the text on the field so u get the name of the item
var xItem = nlapiGetLineItemText('item', 'itemname', i); 
//Reads the text on the field so u get the name of the location
    var xLocation = nlapiGetLineItemText('item', 'location', i); 
        if (xItem == "1003-G" && xLocation == "Leach"){
                alert ("REMINDER – Glacial is diluted when received. Inventory adjustment to remove 1003-G and add 1003. Divide the total pounds received by 0.2 and calculate the new cost per pound. REMINDER - Inventory valuation should be net $0");
                break;
            }
```

Call "is1003GandLeach()" in the saveRecord event in the client script you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Jordan you made mistake i think. if your are checking in Existing record you should have check with that record object. Whatever you have done so far is very correct, **but you have to correct your code on 5th and 6th line** like below

```
function is1003GandLeach()
 {
   var record = nlapiLoadRecord('itemreceipt', nlapiGetRecordId());
   var count = record.getLineItemCount('item');

   for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
  {
    var xItem = record.getLineItemValue('item', 'itemname', i);
    var xLocation = record.getLineItemValue('item', 'location', i);

       if (xItem == "1003-G" && xLocation == "Leach")
          {
              alert ("REMINDER – Glacial is diluted when received. Inventory    adjustment to remove 1003-G and add 1003. Divide the total pounds received by 0.2 and calculate the new cost per pound. REMINDER - Inventory valuation should be net $0");
              break;
          }
   }
  nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
 }
```